# Light microscope specimen size

Tags: microbiology, homework, microscopy

I was going through sample questions for Science Olympiad, and one of the questions went like this:

> A cell is observed through a light microscope at 4x magnification. The cell takes up about half of the visual field. What is the approximate length of this organism?

I know from prior knowledge that a cell can be anywhere from $10$ to $100$ micrometers, but I don't know how to figure out a cell's size with the information I'm given. Usually when I do problems like this, I am given the size of the field of view. Is that not needed to solve this problem?

Comment: http://pob.k12.ny.us/cms/lib/NY01001456/Centricity/Domain/517/Measuring%20%20With%20a%20Microscope%20SB201312_9_13.pdf Have a look his should help..

Comment: @Polisetty Those slides just pretty much review what I already know... is there something I missed?

Comment: Is this an mcq? since the question says, "approximate", you can assume the fov to be 5mm for 4x. Though it changes also with the magnification of your eyepiece. We were told to remember the fov values for 4x, 10x, 40x, 100x.. approximately - 5mm, 2mm, 0.5mm, 0.2mm These were approximates. This was a long time back.. maybe someone else can answer better.. Here's a full table - http://www.seoenterprises.com/shop/pages.php?pageid=12

Comment: @Polisetty thanks for the chart; also what's a mcq?

Comment: a 'multiple choice question'. huehuehue.

Comment: @Polisetty lol, no

Comment: Some cells can be much larger than the range you listed, examples that come to mind are some eggs (the yolk of a normal chicken egg is a favorite example), some algae, and I believe some amoebae too; not a bad rule of thumb for mammalian somatic cells but just a hint to not be overly focused on what is "typical" if the question doesn't define or depend on it.

Comment: @BryanKrause Never thought of that...biology textbooks always say cells are between 10 and 100 micrometers

Comment: @suomynonA Do you have a source for that? I wouldn't be surprised if there was a "typically" in that sentence, or if the topic was clearly relating to non-gamete animal cells, or something like that, because that certainly isn't true overall.

Comment: @BryanKrause The science olympiad rules, I copied it verbatim

Comment: @suomynonA I meant for your statement that "biology textbooks always say..." - I'm assuming that isn't written in the science olympiad rules?

Comment: @BryanKrause I just checked Campbell biology, it says "most cells" so I guess there are exceptions

Comment: The best  "approximate" answer in my opinion is: 2 times the length of the visual field :P